# Load multiple audio files one with jquery and have a callback on complete

Tags: jquery, ios, audio

I have many sounds used in a page and i decided to load them on a sound icon click so it will work on mobile/touch devices. See below the code

```
var greenBetsound = document.getElementById('greenBet_sound');
jQuery('.soundIcon').click(function(){  
    if(!jQuery('.soundIcon').hasClass('soundIconOn')){
        jQuery('body').addClass('audioOn');
        jQuery('.soundIcon').removeClass('soundIconOff').addClass('soundIconOn');
        greenBetsound.load();
        firstReelStopsound.load();
        secondReelStopsound.load();
        thirdReelStopsound.load();
        fourthReelStopsound.load();
        fifthReelStopsound.load();
        creditsTranferWithNoClubMeter.load();
        bonusGamesStart.load();
        jackpotSound.load();
        winline1Combsound.load();
        winline2Combsound.load();
        winline3Combsound.load();
        winline4Combsound.load();
        winline5Combsound.load();
        winline6Combsound.load();
        mysterycountsound.load();
    }else{
        jQuery('body').removeClass('audioOn');
        jQuery('.soundIcon').removeClass('soundIconOn').addClass('soundIconOff');  
    } 
});
```

Here is the markup

```
<audio id="greenBet_sound" src="sounds/sound21.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

How can I have them all loaded at once in one line and have a callback on complete of loading so i allow users to navigate into the webpage only after the sounds will be fully loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not duplicate, my case is different @guest271314

Comment: How is requirement at present Question different from Answer at linked Question? Use `Promise.all()`, `Promise` constructor to load all media resources, when all resources loaded, use chained `.then()` to perform tasks.

Comment: Am not sure if the code provided in the answer is working on mobile devices. Also i don't need to play them after each other just load @guest271314. And have a callback when all audios will be loaded fully not on each one

Comment: The `javascript` at linked Question should return same result at mobile devices. `.then()` chained to `Promise.all()` will not be called until all `Audio` elements `canplay` event has been dispatched. You can omit calling `.play()`.

Comment: How the urls in the audio files array can be dynamic cause imagine file names can be changed at any time @guest271314. Am testing currently the promise par

Comment: _"How the urls in the audio files array can be dynamic cause imagine file names can be changed at any time"_ Not sure what you mean by "dynamic"? Why would file names be changed?

Comment: It is for being safe. Regarding the promise on ios it is not working i just tested, Android works, i added an alert in then and it is not doing anything @guest271314

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting same result at ios.

Comment: Yes jquery is included @guest271314.My main issue is with ios that's why i was trying to do them via jquery load

Comment: Try chaining `.catch(function(e) {console.log(e)})` to `Promise.all()` call to determine if an error occurs. What is expected result of using  jQuery `.load()`? You have not passed any parameters to the `.load()` function call.

Comment: I added the catch but it is not showing anything. Load just loaded the audio file and it was working on ios @guest271314

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue? Does `$.get()` return same result as `.load()` ? If yes, you can use `$.when()`, `$.get()` to load files. Though `Promise.all()` should also return same result.

Comment: Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/anahitdev/hv7xwabg/ @guest271314

Comment: I also tried with get and when and result is not the same. So how you see my question is not duplicate and the issue exists @guest271314

Comment: The `javascript` at jsfiddle returns expected result, here.

Comment: When you click on On you see the alert with IOS @guest271314?

Comment: Have not tried ios. Are sounds not audible at https://jsfiddle.net/hv7xwabg/1/?

Comment: As i told my issue is with IOS, other than that i don't have issues. If you try on ios you will not see the alert @guest271314

Comment: Which version of ios are you using? See http://caniuse.com/promises, https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

Comment: I need it working on all so it does not make sense. Need cross platform solution @guest271314.

Comment: @AnahitGhararyan You can use `Audio` constructor or `<audio>` element, `canplay` event; see post.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have them all loaded at once in one line and have a callback
>   on complete of loading so i allow users to navigate into the webpage
>   only after the sounds will be fully loaded?

One approach is to use `Audio` constructor or `document.createElement("audio")` to create `AudioNode` and `jQuery.holdReady()`. Create an array to store audio nodes, attach `canplay` event to `AudioNode`. At `canplay` event check if array containing audio nodes is equal to array containing media sources, if true call `jQuery.holdReady(false)`. You can then use `Array.prototype.slice()` to create a copy of audio nodes, `Array.prototype.shift()` to play back audio nodes in sequence.

```js
jQuery.holdReady(true);

const audioAddress = [
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/sound21.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/toBasic.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/wheelStop1.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/wheelStop2.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/wheelStop3.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/wheelStop4.mp3",
  "http://grandspinfinal.ipoint.com.mt/sounds/wheelStop5.mp3"
];

const tracks = [];

audioAddress.forEach(function(src) {
  var audio = document.createElement("audio");
  audio.oncanplay = function() {
    tracks.push(this);
    if (tracks.length === audioAddress.length) {
      jQuery.holdReady(false);
    }
  }
  audio.src = src;
});

$(function() {
  let mix = tracks.slice(0);

  function playTracks() {
    let track = mix.shift();
    track.onended = function() {
      if (mix.length) {
        playTracks();
      }
    }
    track.play();
  }

  playTracks();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```